# Expected response to contain an object but got an array error in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi i have tried creating a simple sign in service, but ended up with this error.

**My service**

```
foodModule.factory('Login', function($resource){
    return $resource('http://localhost:1337/User/', {}, {

    });
});
```

**my fucntion**

```
$scope.signIn=function(){
    console.log('Sign in function works');
    console.log($scope.user.signemail);
    console.log($scope.user.signpassword);
    $scope.signuser=Login.get({email:$scope.user.signemail,password:$scope.user.signpassword});
    console.log($scope.signuser);
}
```

Error:

```
Error: [$resource:badcfg] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$resource/badcfg?p0=get&p1=object&p2=array
```

Am i doing anything wrong here? I hope i should mention the method properly, any idea on this error??

Comment: The link in error explains everything: http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$resource/badcfg?p0=get&p1=object&p2=array

Answer (score 1):

resource `get` should return a single object, but in your case, an array is being returned.

The problem could be that you are trying to do login using `GET`. Normally login is achieved using http `POST`. Most probably you should use `Login.post` instead of `Login.get`

Comment: See the browser console what url is being hit. Is it the login url? Are the parameters passed correctly? If it is a post the data goes in body.

Answer (score 0):

The parameters of $resources are as `resource(url, paramDefaults, actions)`.

In first you already have url and blank paramDefaults are acceptable but in last parameters you need to specify explictly isArray: false .

So action can be like:-

```
'query': {method: 'GET', isArray: false }
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your $resource configuration matches the actual format of the data returned from the server.

For more information: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource